# Solving $y^{(6)}+ m^2y^{(4)} - m^4y'' - m^6y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving the differential equation $y^{(6)}+ m^2y^{(4)} - m^4y'' - m^6y = 0$

This is a linear differential equation with constant coefficients. The associated polynomial is:

$$r^6 + m^2r^4 - m^4y^2 - m^6 = 0$$

Obviously, $m$ and $-m$ are zeros, so after applying Horner's rule twice, I found:

$$(r-m)(r+m)(r^4 - 2m^2r^2 + m^4) = 0$$

which can be further factored:

$$(r-m)^3(r+m)^3 = 0$$

Therefore, we can conclude that the solution is:

$$y = c_1e^{mx} + c_2xe^{mx}+ c_3x^2e^{mx} + c_4e^{-mx}+c_5xe^{-mx}+c_6x^2e^{-mx}$$

Is this correct? My book gives the answer

$$y = c_1e^{mx} + c_2e^{-mx} + (c_3 + xc_4)\cos(mx) + (c_5 + xc_6)\sin(mx)$$

Are both answers equivalent or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an error in your factorization. Letting $s=r^2$, $n=m^2$, the polynomial
$$r^6+m^2r^4-m^4r^2-m^6=0$$
becomes
$$s^3+ns^2-n^2s-n^3=0$$
which can be factorized as
$$(s-n)(s^2+2ns+n^2) = (s-n)(s+n)^2=0$$
And so the solutions for $s$ are $s=\pm n = \pm m^2$. Thus, we have $r = \pm m, \pm im$. The $\pm m$ have multiplicity $1$, and the $\pm im$ have multiplicity $2$, and so the general solution is
$$y = c_1e^{mx}+c_2e^{-mx}+(c_3+c_4x)\cos(mx)+(c_5+c_6x)\sin(mx)$$
Put simply, the $-2m^2r^2$ in your factorization should be positive.